# Rename files 000...001...002... to 001...002...003

Tags: rename, file-extension, bulk

I wanted to download a 50gb file, from an internet archive. It was downloading up to 300kb/s and it was going to take days. So I wrote a script to download the files in chunks, and upload to Google Drive without caching and filling up my 20GB server. I now have files `.000` to `.082`.

I would like to open this in 7z, but I was a bit careless and started with `000` instead of `001`, I'd rather not combine them first, so how would I bulk rename these files to increment by 1, so that I get file exts like `001`,`002`,`003`?

I tried opening them in 7z, but it only reads the .000 file.

I have access to windows and linux, I tried Bulk File Renamer Utility, for windows but it doesn't seem to like incrementing file extentions by using its `Numbering (10)` is there a way to do it in Bulk File Renamer Utility, or otherwise how would I got about using the linux command line to rename them all?

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm sure this could be done with some sort of 1 line linux command. I hardly call that a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one-liner should work. Tested on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

It works by using `ls -r` to list files in reverse order, and then—via the magic of math—just adding `+1` to each file extension.

The script assumes that you have files named with a pattern such as this:

```
test.000
test.001
test.002
test.003
```

And will rename them as follows when done:

```
test.001
test.002
test.003
test.004
```

Here is a “dry run” version that will simply echo the command for your review:

```
ls -r | while read f; do echo mv "${f}" "${f%.*}.$(printf '%03d' $(expr ${f##*.} + 1))"; done
```

And just remove that `echo` to get it to run and do it’s thing like this:

```
ls -r | while read f; do mv "${f}" "${f%.*}.$(printf '%03d' $(expr ${f##*.} + 1))"; done
```

Comment: In general parsing `ls` is not recommended. I'm sure you know it, less experienced users may get confused though. So let's say it clearly: [one shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); but the whole answer is tailored to filenames following the strict pattern, this makes parsing `ls` rather safe, so it's a reasonable exception. Additionally this "dry run" adds to the safety. Upvoted.